# Looking for help on writing a mathematical argument clearly and concisely

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-verification, prime-numbers, totient-function

> Let $p_n$ be the $n$th prime and $a < p_n$ be a non-negative integer .
>
> Let $f(a,p_n)$ be the number of integers $x$ such that:
>
> $$a(p_{n-1}\#) < x < (a+1)(p_{n-1}\#) \text{ and } \gcd(x,p_n\#)=1$$

- where $p\#$ is the [primorial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primorial) for $p$
- and $\gcd(a,b)$ is the [greatest common denominator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greatest_common_divisor) between $a$ and $b$.

I am trying to show that if $\varphi(x)$ is the [Euler Totient function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function), then:

> $$f(a,p_n) > \varphi(p_{n-1}\#) - \varphi(p_{n-2}\#)$$

Assuming that my reasoning is correct (which it may not be), my goal is to state the following argument as clearly and concisely as possible.

Here is my argument:

> (1)  $f(a,p_n) < \varphi(p_{n-1}\#)$ since $\varphi(p_{n-1}\#) = $ the number of integers $x$ such that:
>   $$a(p_{n-1}\#) < x < (a+1)(p_{n-1}\#) \text{ and } \gcd(x,p_{n-1}\#)=1$$
>
> (2) Let $g(a,p_{n-1},p_n)$ be the number of integers $x$ such that:
>   $$a(p_{n-1}\#) < x < (a+1)(p_{n-1}\#) \text{ and } \mathbb{lpf}(x)=p_n$$ 
>   where lpf(x) is the [least prime factor](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LeastPrimeFactor.html) for $x$.
>
> (3)  $g(a,p_{n-1},p_n) \le \varphi(p_{n-2}\#)$ since $g(a,p_{n-1},p_n) \le g(a,p_{n-1},p_{n-1}) = \varphi(p_{n-2}\#)$
>
> (4)  So the conclusion follows since $f(a,p_n) = \varphi(p_{n-1}\#) - g(a,p_{n-1},p_n)$

Is my argument valid? Is my argument as clear and concise as it could be?  Is there an easier way to make the same point?

---

Edit: Adding details on (3) in response to a comment:

> (3A): $g(a,p_{n-1},p_{n-1}) = \varphi(p_{n-2}\#)$

- $\mathbb{lpf(x)}=p_{n-1}$ if and only if $\exists y$ where $x=y p_{n-1}$ and:

$$a(p_{n-2}\#) < y < (a+1)(p_{n-2}\#) \text{ and } \mathbb{lpf}(y)\ge p_{n-1}$$

- The number of such integers $y$ is $\varphi(p_{n-2}\#)$.  (I can provide more information on this if needed)

> (3B): $g(a,p_{n-1},p_{n}) \le g(a,p_{n-1},p_{n-1})$

- $\mathbb{lpf(x)}=p_n$ if and only if $\exists y$ where $x=y p_n$ and:

$$a\left(\frac{p_{n-1}\#}{p_n}\right) < y < (a+1)\left(\frac{p_{n-1}\#}{p_n}\right) \text{ and } \mathbb{lpf}(y)\ge p_n$$

- The conclusion follows since:

$$a\left(\frac{p_{n-1}\#}{p_n}\right) < y < (a+1)\left(\frac{p_{n-1}\#}{p_n}\right) < a\left(\frac{p_{n-1}\#}{p_n}\right) + p_{n-2}\#$$

- which contains $\varphi(p_{n-2}\#)$ integers $x$ where $\mathbb{lpf}(x) \ge p_{n-1}$

Comment: (3) is not clear to me.

Comment: Please let me know if (3) is still not clear.  I've added details to fill in the previous gap.

Comment: I would expect in all cases, $g(a,p_{n-1},p_{n+1}) < f(a,p_{n-1}\#)$.  Here's an example.  Let $a=0,n=4$ so that $f(0,30)=8$.  In this case, $g(0,5,11) = 1$

Comment: $\gcd(x,p_n\#)=1$ iff $\mathbb{lpf}(x) \ge p_{n+1}$  For example, if $\mathbb{lpf}(x)=p_{n+2}$, then $\gcd(x,p_{n}\#)=1$ and $\mathbb{lpf}(x) \neq p_{n+1}$  lpf=least prime factor.

Comment: I am wondering if you can have equality in (3). If not then your conclusion is correct as given and I don't see a mistake.

Comment: With help from Erick Wong, the argument for a strict inequality can be found here: http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1693673/48606 which is enough for the argument since it shows there is an $x$ with lpf$(x) \ge  p_{n-1}$ found between $w$ and $w + \frac{p_{n-2}\#}{p_{n-1}}$ since there is one found between $w$ and $w + p_{n-4}\#$ with $p_{n-2}p_{n-3} > 2 p_{n-2} > p_{n-1}$